# htmlhelper does not contain a definition for kendo in ASP.NET MVC RAZOR

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to install kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC application and I am getting following error. htmlhelper does not contain a definition for kendo

I have working ASP.NET project with kendo ui and I have copied require kendo styles and script in require folder, added namespace detail in web.config, add references in bundleConfig.cs and and kendo.mvc dll in reference. I have followed following tutorial

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5

I am not what I am missing, also both application are ASP.NET MVC 5.

test code is as following which I am trying to make it work

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let ASP.NET MVC know of the Kendo.Mvc.UI namespace where the server-side wrappers are. To do this, update the web.config file of the web application.

Step 1 Open Views/Web.config, or root Web.config if using ASPX.

Step 2 Locate the namespaces tag.

Step 3 Append an add tag to the namespaces tag.

EXAMPLE

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
</namespaces>
```

Step 4 Add a binding redirect to your current System.Web.Mvc version.

EXAMPLE

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-[version-of-kendo-dll-that-you-are-using]" newVersion="[version-of-kendo-dll-that-you-are-using]" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I have done all those steps but its still not working

Comment: Try adding `@using Kendo.Mvc.UI` in the _ViewStart.cshtml file inside the Views folder

Comment: Also check if the namespace is added in the web.config inside the Views folder and not in the web.config of the root folder

Comment: I have added in controller class using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI; and is recognizing but it still not working in razor view pages for some of reason

Comment: have you tried and checked by adding in the _ViewStart.cshtml file?

Comment: many thanks, I have added references in _ViewStart.cshtml and it works

Comment: For me, it still didn't work until I built the project and restarted the solution.

Answer (score 1):

After Installing Kendo Ui Make sure to Add this using On top of your Layout Page:

@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).